# What is the meaning of the following coding in pyteaser?

Tags: python

I am currently using pyteaser to do a summarization and it works well. I am looking at the source code but i do not understand the following coding even with the help of the comment written below. Can anyone explain it a bit more ?

```
def split_sentences(text):
    '''
    The regular expression matches all sentence ending punctuation and splits the string at those points.
    At this point in the code, the list looks like this ["Hello, world", "!" ... ]. The punctuation and all quotation marks
    are separated from the actual text. The first s_iter line turns each group of two items in the list into a tuple,
    excluding the last item in the list (the last item in the list does not need to have this performed on it). Then,
    the second s_iter line combines each tuple in the list into a single item and removes any whitespace at the beginning
    of the line. Now, the s_iter list is formatted correctly but it is missing the last item of the sentences list. The
    second to last line adds this item to the s_iter list and the last line returns the full list.
    '''

    sentences = regex_split('(?<![A-Z])([.!?]"?)(?=\s+\"?[A-Z])', text)
    s_iter = zip(*[iter(sentences[:-1])] * 2)
    s_iter = [''.join(map(str,y)).lstrip() for y in s_iter]
    s_iter.append(sentences[-1])
    return s_iter
```

Answer (score 6):

### Line 1

First, we have a regular expression `(?<![A-Z])([.!?]"?)(?=\s+\"?[A-Z])`. Here is the output of compiling it with the `re.DEBUG` flag:

```
assert_not -1 
  in 
    range (65, 90)
subpattern 1 
  in 
    literal 46
    literal 33
    literal 63
  max_repeat 0 1 
    literal 34 
assert 1 
  max_repeat 1 65535 
    in 
      category category_space
  max_repeat 0 1 
    literal 34 
  in 
    range (65, 90)
```

First, we look for something that *isn't* preceded by a capital letter `[A-Z]` (a negative lookbehind assertion with `?<!`, i.e. `assert_not`). Then, we look for a punctuation mark (one of `.!?`), followed by zero or one double quotes `"`. Finally, we check that our something *is* followed by one or more whitespace characters `\s+`, zero or one double quotes `\"`, and a capital letter `[A-Z]` (this part is a lookahead assertion, i.e. `assert`).

This regex will only actually match the `([.!?]"?)` part, i.e. the punctuation possibly followed by a quote.

`regex_split` is [an alias for `re.split`](https://github.com/xiaoxu193/PyTeaser/blob/master/pyteaser.py#L3) here. So, `text` is split before and after each matched part: the punctuation and possible quote, not preceded by a capital letter, and followed by whitespace, maybe a quote, and a capital letter. For example:

```
'John was tired. So was Sally. But was Bob? I don\'t know! Huh.'
```

would give the following `sentences`:

```
['John was tired', '.', ' So was Sally', '.', ' But was Bob', '?', " I don't know", '!', ' Huh.']
```

### Line 2

Next, we remove the last element of `sentences` (because this operation doesn't need to be done on it; we add it back in line 4) with `[:-1]`:

```
['John was tired', '.', ' So was Sally', '.', ' But was Bob', '?', " I don't know", '!']
```

convert it to an iterator with `iter`, put it in a list (`[]`):

```
[<list_iterator object at ...>]
```

Now, when we do `zip(*[<list iterator ...>] * 2)`, what we're doing is zipping two references to the *same* iterator object together (unpacked by the unary `*` operator). This way, when `zip` iterates over the first reference to it once, it consumes one sentence, and then when it iterates over the second reference to it once (to pair up with the first reference), it has already consumed one sentence, and so moves on to the corresponding punctuation. Thanks to [@SeanVieira in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20963461/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-following-coding-in-pyteaser/20963697?noredirect=1#comment31491998_20963697) for a concise explanation of this. This gives us the following result:

```
[('John was tired', '.'), (' So was Sally', '.'), (' But was Bob', '?'), (" I don't know", '!')]
```

So we have each sentence paired with its ending punctuation (again, except for the last one).

### Line 3

Now, we join the sentence back to its punctuation using `''.join(...)` (I think the `map` there is superfluous):

```
['John was tired.', ' So was Sally.', ' But was Bob?', " I don't know!"]
```

and strip leading whitespace with `.lstrip()`:

```
['John was tired.', 'So was Sally.', 'But was Bob?', "I don't know!"]
```

### Line 4

Finally, we tack the last sentence back on, giving us:

```
['John was tired.', 'So was Sally.', 'But was Bob?', "I don't know!", ' Huh. ']
```

### Line 5

Finally, we `return`.

Comment: Most of this seems straightforward, and you've explained it excellently, but I can't get my head around line 2- from testing it myself, it seems like the `iter` call is *not* superfluous, but seems to be key to getting the right answer out.

Comment: `iter` by itself would be superfluous - `[iter(lst)] * 2` is most definitely not. It creates a list with two references to *the same* iterator and passes them to `zip`, which is directly responsible for the `(sentence, punctuation)` tuple (without `iter` you would get `(sentence, same-sentence)` then `(punctuation, same-punctuation)`.

Comment: @SeanVieira: Ah, that makes sense. I was beating my head against that one for a while, so thanks.

Comment: @SeanVieira Thanks, I was trying to figure out how best to explain that (should've tested before claiming it was superfluous...). I've incorporated your comment into my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Line 2 of this function seems to be much harder to understand than the rest, so I've unpacked it here to make it a bit more readable. Hopefully this makes it clearer that the `zip` call is working on two copies of the *same* iterator:

```
def split_sentences(text):
    sentences = regex_split('(?<![A-Z])([.!?]"?)(?=\s+\"?[A-Z])', text)
    sentences_iter = iter(sentences[:-1])
    s_iter = zip(sentences_iter, sentences_iter)
    s_iter = [''.join(map(str,y)).lstrip() for y in s_iter]
    s_iter.append(sentences[-1])
    return s_iter
```